# CSS div elements overlapping with screen resize

Tags: css

This is only for chrome browser no spirte buttons on others...

I have a site that is supposed to reorganize with landscape and portrait views on a tablet and phone. It looks ok on Desktop and Tablet but when viewed on a phone all the elements overlap. Here's the site: http://cit-blogs.com/R00092575/responsive/index.html

The CSS for the overlapping divs looks like this:

```
@media (min-width: 480px) and (orientation landscape){
    .leftPanel {left: 0%; position: absolute; top: 190%; width: 33%; height: 33%;}
    .buttons {left: 45%; position: absolute; top: 190%; width: 40%;}
    .rightPanel {left: 67%; position: absolute; top: 190%; width: 33%;
}
```

And

```
@media screen and (max-width: 380px){
    .buttons {clear: both; left: 15%; position: absolute; top: 80%; width: 40%;}
    .leftPanel {clear: both; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; top: 90%; width:100%;}
    .rightPanel {clear: both; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; top: 130%; width:100%;}
}
```

I tried putting a div around the elements that get overlapped and another one around the divs that overlap but it didn't work. I am new to CSS and not sure what to do, static positioning doesn't seem to put all the divs horizontally across the screen so I don't think I can use that as seen in the Help page on my site.

The actual CSS has one of the panels set to invisible on the phone size. This was to prove that the particular CSS was being seen. Tablet and Desktop Css is getting seen. Can anyone tell me how to fix the CSS for the phone so that the buttons, advert and Twitter feed don't overlap the text and video but also realign to the horizontal and vertical positions as required for landscape and portait views. HERE IS THE FIDDLE `http://jsfiddle.net/Sheeno_no_no/dZCjL/`

Comment: proabably you get help if you set up a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I think you can view the code with firefox's firebug add on.

Comment: @user2988869 You're missing the point. We encourage users to port their problems over to a Fiddle so that the link will remain relevant and in context. Linking to an external URL that is subjected to link rot and content changes does not add anything valuable to the discussion.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about link rot. here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Sheeno_no_no/dZCjL/

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about your .buttons being in the middle of the screen, you have a media query in your stylesheet at line 242 that places them 52% from the top of the screen.  you probably want to hide the twitter feed at that screen width as well.
if you are using the buttons as a footer, you could fix them to the bottom when in tablet or desktop and then just have the `postion:static` on the smaller screens so it is the last element on the page when the user scrolls to the bottom.
also you may have a closing ; missing somewhere in your css.  I think thats why you see the words TV and Music

Validate your html and css [at W3C](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the closing advice but for the other stuff the add, the twitter feed and the buttons have to be horizontal across the screen in landscape mode and vertical in portait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted. Made a container div `.bottomBox {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:100%;}` but the leftPanel and rightPanel to float left and right respectively eg `.rightPanel {float: right; width: 30%;}` and put the buttons and login box into a list `<ul> <li></li>` with the buttons CSS to `.buttons {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:10%;}` This gives panels on either side with the login and buttons in the middle without any overlapping. For portait mode simply set the panels to the same as the bottomBox.